# pygame sprite.Group - passing arguments out of a Group

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I'm trying out pygame, using Sprites & Groups, and getting myself a little confused around passing arguments.

Basically I have a wrapper class MyGame() as my_game(). In that I have pygame.sprite.Group() - all_sprites.

I then have a class Alien(pygame.sprite.Sprite) for my aliens, and I add each alien to my all_sprites Group.

I want my Group of aliens to track across the screen (which they do) and then all drop as a block, a group (which they don't).

I can loop through my all_sprites.Group in my main loop after the self.all_sprites.update() and see if alien.rect.right > WIDTH or alien.rect.left < 0 , then loop through the Group again calling alien.end_row() then break the loop so it doesn't run for each alien on the screen edge, but that seems very clunky.

I've tried setting a flag in MyGame self.alien_drop = False but when I try to set my_game.alien_drop = True in the Alien class, it doesn't recognise my_game - not defined. I'm a little confused as MyGame is creating the instances of Alien, so they should be enclosed by the scope of MyGame?

I can pass MyGame self.alien_drop into my Alien init() but when I update the Alien self.alien_drop it doesn't update MyGame.alien_drop. Which I get because it's created a new variable local to Alien.

There doesn't seem to be a way to pass an argument through Group.update() which I guess is because it's just calling the .update() on all Sprite inside the group. I can't see an easy way to modify the Group.update() function so that I can pass values, and in fairness I probably don't want to go mucking around in there anyway.

I also can't return True back through update().

I'm kinda stuck at this point...

I know the self.aliens.row_end() probably won't work, I'll have to loop through self.aliens and call each alien.row_end(), but at the moment it's not even getting to that point.

```
import pygame

WIDTH = 360 # width of our game window
HEIGHT = 480 # height of our game window
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)

class MyGame():
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.alien_drop = False
        for row_index in range(4):
            for column_index in range(6):
                alien = Alien(20 + (column_index * 40), 20 + (row_index *40))
                alien.add(self.all_sprites)
        while True:
            self.screen.fill(BLACK)
            self.all_sprites.update()
            if self.alien_drop:
                self.aliens.row_end()
            self.all_sprites.draw(self.screen)
            pygame.display.update()
            self.clock.tick(60)

class Alien(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((25, 25))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (x, y)
        self.image.fill(GREEN)
        self.dx = 1

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.dx
        if self.rect.right >= WIDTH or self.rect.left <= 0:
            my_game.alien_drop = True

    def row_end(self):
        self.dx *= -1
        self.rect.y += 40

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_game = MyGame()
```

Answer (score 1):

So to do the traditional [Space Invaders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Invaders) move and drop, the entire row drops when *any* of the invaders hits either side.

In the example below I have modified the `Alien.update()` to detect when the screen-side is hit, but if-so, only set a Boolean flag `Alien.drop` to True.

The algorithm becomes:  First move all the aliens.  Next, check if *any* alien hit the side-wall by checking this flag.  If so, move *every* alien down 1 step & stop checking.

The `Alien.row_end()` function moves the aliens down.  It also needs to clear the `Alien.drop` flag, so they don't all move down again.

```
import pygame

WIDTH = 360 # width of our game window
HEIGHT = 480 # height of our game window
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)

class MyGame():
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.alien_drop = False
        for row_index in range(4):
            for column_index in range(6):
                alien = Alien(20 + (column_index * 40), 20 + (row_index *40))
                alien.add(self.all_sprites)

        exiting = False
        while not exiting:
            # Handle events
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
                    exiting = True  # exit this loop

            self.screen.fill(BLACK)
            self.all_sprites.update()
            for alien1 in self.all_sprites:
                if ( alien1.shouldDrop() ):
                    ### If any alien drops, we all drop
                    for alien2 in self.all_sprites:
                        alien2.row_end()
                    break  # only drop once

            if self.alien_drop:
                self.aliens.row_end()
            self.all_sprites.draw(self.screen)
            pygame.display.update()
            self.clock.tick(60)

class Alien(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((25, 25))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (x, y)
        self.image.fill(GREEN)
        self.dx = 1
        self.drop = False  # should I drop-down a level

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.dx
        if self.rect.right >= WIDTH or self.rect.left <= 0:
            self.drop = True
        else:
            self.drop = False

    def shouldDrop( self ):
        """ In this alien in a position where it should drop down
            one row in the screen-space (i.e.: it's hit a side)  """
        return self.drop

    def row_end(self):
        self.dx *= -1
        self.rect.y += 40
        self.drop = False    # drop drop again just yet

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_game = MyGame()
```

Comment: Yes, that for ... if ... for .. break is what I've implemented as a fix but feels cumbersome. I'm already called an update() on each alien so I'd like to capture the drop as part of that. There could be other things to check also, and having to loop through the whole Group everytime (when I'm already doing it for update) doesn't seem optimal.

Comment: @JohnBradford - Maybe you could wrap your Alien Horde in a grouping class that keeps track of whether one of them has hit the side.  It's always a toss-up answering questions, you try to make the minimal amount of changes to the OP's program, even if it's not necessarily the best way forward.

Comment: yes, I see what you mean. It means looping through all the aliens somewhere to check if they've hit the side, rather than the aliens notifying the 'parent' class themselves. Whether that's in the MyGame class, or a AlienHorde class. Thanks